# Adding unwanted character to comma in mysql - codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

This is the codeigniter controller statement to get the data from mysql

```
$result = $this->db->select("GROUP_CONCAT(Service_name SEPARATOR ', ' ) AS service_names")
                           ->where('Service_boid', $boId)
                           ->get('service');
```

Here the problem is, a syntax error in mysql because while echoed the query:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(Service_name SEPARATOR ', `'` ) AS service_names FROM (`service_info`) WHERE `Service_boid` = '4'
```

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '`) AS service_names FROM (`service_info`) WHERE`Service_boid`
>   = '4' at line 1

An unwanted character is appending to the separator as shown above. Other than direct query execution (sql query is executing through mysqli_query()) any solution to solve this?

Note : I want ', ' as the separator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$result = $this->db->select("GROUP_CONCAT(Service_name SEPARATOR ', ' ) AS service_names", false)
->where('Service_boid', $boId)
->get('service');
```

Please note that adding a second parameter to the `select()` will not try to escape your select statement, and comma(',') is the default separator.

Answer (score 2):

Remove space from code:

```
"GROUP_CONCAT(Service_name SEPARATOR ', ' ) AS service_names")
                                       ^
```

Use like this:

```
"GROUP_CONCAT(Service_name SEPARATOR ',' ) AS service_names")
```

> If You want to use ', ' as the delimiter

Then use `false` as second parameter.

```
$this->db->select("GROUP_CONCAT(Service_name SEPARATOR ', ' ) AS service_names", false)
```

> [**$this->db->select()**](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#select) accepts an optional second parameter. If you set
>   it to FALSE, CodeIgniter will not try to protect your field or table
>   names with backticks. This is useful if you need a compound select
>   statement.

Comment: No I want that as the delimiter which I have already added as a note.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid protecting your field query by CI you need to use `false` as second parameter to the `select` function. See the doc [$this->db->select();](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html)

SO your query will be like this

```
$result = $this->db->select("GROUP_CONCAT(Service_name SEPARATOR ', ' ) AS service_names",false)
->where('Service_boid', $boId)
->get('service');
```